# Given a list as string, how to convert back to list of numbers?

Tags: r, string, list, type-conversion

I am given a string which was a list of numbers:

```
s <- "[14,7,5,3,4,0,1,7,2,3,1,18,13,4,23,7,8,8,11,18,15,6,2,10,2,4,8,5,11,5,1,5,2,4,3,1,6,8,5,5,3,1,1,4,5,2,9,3,4,11,11,14,3,12,2,6,0,0,15,1,18,5,3,6,6,6]"
```

Please guide me how to convert it back to regular `list` of numbers?
I have tried using `strsplit`, `as.data.frame` but it seems very long.
I want something efficient and creative.

Comment: You could try `stringi` `as.integer(stri_extract_all(s, regex = "\\d+")[[1]])`

Comment: @akrun Would you be so kind and explain? I have tried it, but it doesn't work for me, keep trying.

Comment: Have you loaded `library(stringi)` after installing it.  In `R`, you can store as a `vector` after extracting the numbers with regex `\\d+` (one or more digits)

Comment: Sure, there was a conflict there, reloaded. Now it works. Thanks a lot dear @akrun! Please add as answer.
Correct me if I am wrong, the stri_extract_all will extract all the items that fits the regex expression and [[1]] will convert it to a list? What the [[1]] means here? To make it 1 dimensional vector?

Comment: I added some description in the solution below

Comment: Dear @akrun thanks a lot for your great answers! I have learnt a lot from your answers!

Comment: Thank you.  Glad to know that my answers were helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) JSON** The input shown in the question is in JSON format so use either the jsonlite or rjson package and it will do the needed string processing for you.

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(s)
```

giving:

```
 [1] 14  7  5  3  4  0  1  7  2  3  1 18 13  4 23  7  8  8 11 18 15  6  2 10  2
[26]  4  8  5 11  5  1  5  2  4  3  1  6  8  5  5  3  1  1  4  5  2  9  3  4 11
[51] 11 14  3 12  2  6  0  0 15  1 18  5  3  6  6  6
```

**2) strapply** If you did want to use string processing anyways then one option would be `strapply` extracting all sequences of digits `"\\d+"` and converting to numeric giving the same output as above.

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(s, "\\d+", as.numeric, simplify = c)
```

**3) scan** or without any packages or regular expressions:

```
scan(text = chartr("[]", "  ", s), sep = ",", quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: @g-grothendieck thank you so so much for this super detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to extract the numbers from the string using `stri_extract` (`stringi` package).  The output of `stri_extract_all` is a `list` of `vector` with `length` 1.  Usually, if there are multiple elements of 's' (here it is a single string), to convert it to a single `vector`, we use `unlist` and then wrap with `as.integer`.  As there is only a single `list` element, we can extract that element with `[[`

```
library(stringi)
as.integer(stri_extract_all(s, regex = "\\d+")[[1]])
```

---

If we split up the code, as mentioned the `stri_extract_all` returns a `list` of length 1.

```
stri_extract_all(s, regex = "\\d+")
#[[1]]####
#[1] "14" "7"  "5"  "3"  "4"  "0"  "1"  "7"  "2"  "3"  "1"  "18" "13" "4"  "23" "7"  "8"  "8"  "11" "18" "15" "6"  "2"  "10"
#[25] "2"  "4"  "8"  "5"  "11" "5"  "1"  "5"  "2"  "4"  "3"  "1"  "6"  "8"  "5"  "5"  "3"  "1"  "1"  "4"  "5"  "2"  "9"  "3" 
#[49] "4"  "11" "11" "14" "3"  "12" "2"  "6"  "0"  "0"  "15" "1"  "18" "5"  "3"  "6"  "6"  "6"
```

Extract the `list` element containing the `vector`

```
stri_extract_all(s, regex = "\\d+")[[1]]
#[1] "14" "7"  "5"  "3"  "4"  "0"  "1"  "7"  "2"  "3"  "1"  "18" "13" "4"  "23" "7"  "8"  "8"  "11" "18" "15" "6"  "2"  "10"
#[25] "2"  "4"  "8"  "5"  "11" "5"  "1"  "5"  "2"  "4"  "3"  "1"  "6"  "8"  "5"  "5"  "3"  "1"  "1"  "4"  "5"  "2"  "9"  "3" 
#[49] "4"  "11" "11" "14" "3"  "12" "2"  "6"  "0"  "0"  "15" "1"  "18" "5"  "3"  "6"  "6"  "6"
```

and then convert the `vector` of `character` elements to `integer`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the R base solution

This line will only extract digits and save it into a list.

```
numbers <- regmatches(s, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", s))
```

Unlisting the list and converting it into numeric.

```
numbers <- as.numeric(unlist(numbers))
```

**Result**

```
 [1] 14  7  5  3  4  0  1  7  2  3  1 18 13  4 23  7  8  8 11 18 15  6  2 10  2  4  8  5 11  5  1  5  2  4
[35]  3  1  6  8  5  5  3  1  1  4  5  2  9  3  4 11 11 14  3 12  2  6  0  0 15  1 18  5  3  6  6  6
```